# Returning distances in meters from Near (Analysis) tool of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, geoprocessing, coordinate-system, wgs84

I'm trying to write a python program that returns the distance from each point in a set to the nearest road.

Specifically, I was looking for any points within 10 meters of the roads.

Both sets of data use WGS84 coordinates.

Near_analysis runs just fine and returns the right results when using `"10 Meters"` for the radius option, but the distances returned are in degrees, and I want them in meters for further analysis.

I know I can use a different projection and get the meter measurements I am looking for, but if Near_analysis can search for a radius that is measured in meters, why can't it return results in meters?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. You know that using a different coordinate system that uses meters will return distances in meters, so why not reproject your data first? [The documentation even states](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001q000000): _The distances calculated by this tool are in the unit of the coordinate system of the input features. If your input is in a geographic coordinate system and you want output distances to be measured in a linear unit...you must first project your input to a projected coordinate system using Project._

Comment: I understand that, but why can't I return meters if I can search using meters. If the tool calculates distances in meters to satisfy my search, why can't I just see those results?

Comment: It's a fair question, but perhaps one better suited for Esri's [ArcGIS Ideas](http://ideas.arcgis.com/) site :)

Comment: Would you be able to update your question to include the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, please?  The [documentation for Near at 10.2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001q000000) looks to have been revised since 10.0 so it will be easier to advise if we know what you are using first.